# Package rdkafka was not found in the pkg-config search path

Tags: go, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Package rdkafka was not found in the pkg-config search path.

Confluent go package is throwing error like so

```
# pkg-config --cflags  -- rdkafka
Package rdkafka was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `rdkafka.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'rdkafka' found
pkg-config: exit status 1
```

how do I fix this ? I tried adding it to the path but no dice ! any suggestions ?

Comment: https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/issues/275

Comment: Can you show how you set your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`?

Answer (score 6):

```
git clone https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka.git
cd librdkafka
./configure --prefix /usr
make
sudo make install
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/lib/pkgconfig/
```

See [doc](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka) for details

Answer (score 0):

`pkg-config` looks at some default directories for the `.pc` files, typically `/usr/lib/pkgconfig` and `/usr/share/pkgconfig`. However some libraries use `/usr/local` as the their installation prefix.

Try searching for `rdkafka.pc` in your `/usr` directory then add the directory to your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`

e.g. `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`

Edit: Here is a discussion about PKG_CONFIG_PATH: https://askubuntu.com/questions/210210/pkg-config-path-environment-variable

Comment: Check this out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/210210/pkg-config-path-environment-variable